# Set ETH price in Solidty

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I made a basic smart contract:

```
contract Coursetro {
    uint counter = 0;
    event SetCounter(uint value);

    function setCounter(uint value) public {
       counter +=1;
       emit SetCounter(value);
   }

   function getCounter() public view returns (uint) {
       return counter;
   }
    
}
```

but i don't know how to set a fixed ETH price for setCounter function

for exemple how can i set the price of 1 ETH to run setCounter function?

So i could just take the 1 ETH and put it on my wallet, as a sale.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to the community. I recommend adding your code to your post directly, so that it is easier to read.

You could use the 'payable' modifier to make the function able to receive ether. Then you can simply make a require statement to check if the value sent was enough. Something like this:

```
function setCounter(uint value) public payable {
   require(msg.value >= 1 ether, "Error msg here");
   // You can additionally return the surplus ether.
   if (msg.value > 1) {
       payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value - 1 ether);
   }
   // Now send ether to your wallet.
   payable("your wallet address").transfer(1 ether);

   // Rest of the logic.
   counter +=1;
   emit SetCounter(value);
}
```

Hope it is useful :)